# biograph.be We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: server, http-1.1

I am pharmacist and i need this site working, but i don't know to do. Maybe it is from server, maybe from me. I am lame with this (html-things).

I go to this site: biograph.be and everything is ok to this point, but if i want to search anything for example : [tpo gene](http://biograph.be/concept/show/C1364508)

this is what happen:

**We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

and that's it.

Here is view-source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More data from http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-headers/:

```
Resource to Request

This tool makes an HTTP request for an object. It displays the request headers, which are the headers your browser sends to the web server when requesting an object. It then displays the response headers, which are the headers the server sends back to the browser along with the object requested. In this case, the request headers are being sent by this tool, not your browser.


+ Advanced Options
 + HTTP Authentication
HTTP Request Headers

GET /concept/show/C1364508 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (WhatsMyIP.org HTTP_Headers) http://whatsmyip.org/ua
Host    biograph.be
Accept  */*
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
HTTP Response Headers

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date    Sun, 09 Nov 2014 12:34:10 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Request-Id    429a8629-937f-4bce-9edb-1a6187fa7a4e
X-Runtime   0.008952
X-Powered-By    Phusion Passenger 4.0.13
Content-Length  643
Status  500 Internal Server Error
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Can you help me or owner of this site?

```
Your Operating System:  Windows 7
Your Date:  Sun Nov 09 2014 03:38:16 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
Current Screen Resolution:  1360x768
Max Screen Resolution:  1360x728
Color depth:    24bit
Colors:     16777216
Your Browser Information
Platform:   Windows
User agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Browser:    Chrome
Browser version:    38.0.2125.111
AOL:    unknown
Is the browser from mobile device:  No
Is the browser a robot:     No
Your browser language:  pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Your request:   Host: www.dnsstuff.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 30
Accept: */*
Origin: http://www.dnsstuff.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrom­e/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSIDNS=jg4ea46l61i3eb49i326r6g1j1; __utmt=1; SelectedTab=tab-1; SelectedToo­l=aboutYou; __utma=114379858.838766346.1415491931.1415491931.1415499564.2; __utm­b=114379858.6.9.1415500695800; __utmc=114379858; __utmz=114379858.1415499564.2.2­.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
The number of pages visited to this browser session:    7 pages
Browser Plugins     
QuickTime Plugin    
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is >= 6,0,0,0
Version: 7,7,6,0

Browser can play QuickTime VR (using QuickTime plugin): true

Browser can play QuickTime Media (with mimetype "video/quicktime"): true
(using QuickTime Player)
DevalVR Plugin  
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is >= 0,8,0,0
Version: 0,9,1,4
Flash Plugin    
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is >= 10,0,0,0
Version: 15,0,0,189
Shockwave Plugin    
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is >= 10,0,0,0
Version: 12,1,3,153
Windows Media Player Plugin     
Plugin status: not installed or not enabled
Version: null

For non-Internet Explorer browsers, we can check if the plugin is associated with (ie. enabled for) certain mimetypes.
This also lets us make sure that a mimetype is not being hijacked by a different plugin...
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/x-mplayer2")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/asx")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/x-ms-wmp")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/fakeMimeType")
    etc...

Browser can play Windows Media (with mimetype "application/x-mplayer2"): false
(Your browser appears to be unable to play media files with mimetype "application/x-mplayer2")

Plugin is scriptable: false
Silverlight Plugin  
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is >= 3,0,0,0
Version: 5,1,30514,0
VLC Player Plugin   
Plugin status: not installed or not enabled
Version: null
Adobe Reader Plugin     
Plugin status: not installed or not enabled
Version: null

For non-Internet Explorer browsers, we can check if the plugin is associated with (ie. enabled for) certain mimetypes.
This also lets us make sure that a mimetype is not being hijacked by a different plugin...
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/pdf")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/vnd.fdf")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/vnd.adobe.xfdf")
    Plugin status: not installed or not enabled (for mimetype "application/fakeMimeType")
    etc...
Generic PDF Reader Plugin   
PDF Reader status: installed & enabled
Browser has "application/pdf" in navigator.mimeTypes array: true
PDF detection: completed ON THE FLY (OTF)
DummyPDF file was used for detection in this browser: false
RealPlayer Plugin   
Plugin status: installed & enabled, version is unknown
Version: null

For non-Internet Explorer browsers, we can check if the plugin is associated with (ie. enabled for) certain mimetypes.
This also lets us make sure that a mimetype is not being hijacked by a different plugin...
    Plugin status: installed & enabled (for mimetype "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin"), version is unknown
    Plugin status: installed but not enabled (for mimetype "application/x-rp-html5videoshim-plugin")
    Plugin status: installed & enabled (for mimetype "application/vnd.rn-realplayer-javascript"), version is unknown
    Plugin status: installed but not enabled (for mimetype "application/fakeMimeType")
    etc...

Browser can play RealPlayer audio (with mimetype "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin"): true
(using RealPlayer)
Java Plugin     
Java (using <applet> and/or <object> tag) installed & enabled: true
Highest Installed Java Version: 1,8,0,25
Java 1,6,0,10 or higher (using <applet> and/or <object> tag) is installed & enabled.
Java detection: completed ON THE FLY (OTF)
Deployment Toolkit browser plugin installed & enabled: false
Next-Generation Java Plugin2 installed & enabled: true
Java vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java plugin name: Java(TM) Platform SE 8 U25
Java plugin description: Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.25.2 for Mozilla browsers
navigator.javaEnabled(): true
```

Please help me.

Comment: This just means that their website is broken, so contact them. Btw, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Sorry, i am just confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If that occurs its a server issue: http://www.biograph.be/about/contact/

Feel free to contact VIB Department of Molecular Genetics if this should happen again!

I work here so I try to keep it working.